# Include all rows from table 1 and summed rows from another

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to sum rows into categories.  I have a table (r) with the categories and a view with the transactions (v).  For the result, I need all categories regardless if there is data in the table v.  Here's the code I have, it only return all rows from the r table when there is corresponding data in v.

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(v.PledgeAmount, 0)) AS Range1Pledge, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT v.CONSTITUENT_ID) AS Range1Count, 
       r.RangeTitle
FROM   view_CASA_KPIDonorPyramidStep2 as v RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        tbl_CASA_KPI_GiftRanges as r ON 
       v.RangeTitle = r.RangeTitle
WHERE  (v.CAMPAIGN_ID = '2018') AND (v.PledgeDate < '2/1/2018') 
GROUP BY r.RangeTitle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `WHERE` logic was moved to `LEFT JOIN` condition in order to prevent filtering of categories that have no transactions
- `RIGHT` join turned into `LEFT`
- *2/1/2018* replaced by locale independent format, assuming that it is *01 Feb 2018*

SQL:

```
SELECT r.RangeTitle,
       SUM(ISNULL(v.PledgeAmount, 0)) AS Range1Pledge, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT v.CONSTITUENT_ID) AS Range1Count           
FROM   tbl_CASA_KPI_GiftRanges as r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN view_CASA_KPIDonorPyramidStep2 as v 

ON       v.RangeTitle = r.RangeTitle 
AND ( (v.CAMPAIGN_ID = '2018') AND (v.PledgeDate < '20180201') )

GROUP BY r.RangeTitle
```

Comment: Great response.  Thanks so much!